# What causes 'The underlying connection was closed' on nginx?

Tags: nginx, connection

We have a payment gateway integration that posts data to a third party URL. The user then completes their payment process and when the transaction is complete the gateway posts back to a URL on our server.

That post is failing and the gateway are reporting the following error:

> ERROR 13326: Couldn't speak to ServerResultURL [https://foo.com/bar].
>
> Full Error Details: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>
> Response object is null

When I post direct to `https://foo.com/bar` I get a 200 response as I'd expect so I'm not sure where this is falling down.

This is on an Ubuntu box running nginx.

What could be causing that issue and how can I find more detail about it and a way to resolve it?

#### EDIT:

For brevity the example above is on a URL of `/bar` but the reality is that I have a rewrite in place (see below). The URL that actually gets posted to is `/themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib/extload.php/cardsave_server/result` so I'm not sure if the rewrite below is what's causing an issue.

I would still assume not as I do get a 200 response when posting via POSTMAN.

```
# http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19296/404-when-sagepay-attempts-to-contact-cartthrob-notification-url-in-nginx
location /themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib/extload.php { 
    rewrite ^(.*) /themes/third_party/cartthrob/lib/extload.php?$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Typical causes of this kind of error**

I bet your server is responding to the POST to /bar with something that the gateway (PaymentSense, right?) doesn't expect. This might be because:

1. The gateway can't reach your Ubuntu box over the network, because a firewall or network hardware between the two is blocking it.
2. Your https cert is bad / expired / self-signed, and the gateway is refusing the connection.
3. A misconfiguration of NGINX or your web application software (PHP, I imagine? or whatever nginx is serving up) is causing /bar to respond with some odd response, like a 30x, or a 50x error page, or possibly with just the wrong response, such as an HTML page.
4. Something else is wrong with the response to the POST.
5. The script/controller running at /bar could be getting unexpected input in the POST request, so you might want to look at the request coming in.
6. You have a network connectivity issue.

I'll leave the first two items for you to troubleshoot, because I don't think that's what you're asking in this question.

**Troubleshooting NGINX Responses**

I recommend configuring it to dump its response into an nginx variable using `body_filter_by_lua` so that you can see what response is coming out. A good example of how to set this up is available [here](https://serverfault.com/a/598045/266454). I think that will lead you understand why /bar is not behaving.

**Troubleshooting NGINX Requests**

If that isn't revealing the cause of this, try logging the request data. You can do that with something like:

```
location = /bar {
  log_format postdata $request_body;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/postdata.log  postdata;
  fastcgi_pass php_cgi;
}
```

Review the request headers and body of this POST, and if the error isn't immediately apparent, try to replay the exact same request (using an HTTP client that gives you complete control, such as `curl`) and debug what is happening with /bar. Is nginx running the script/controller that you think it should be running when you make an identical POST to /bar? Add logging to the /bar script/controller process.

Use interactive debugging if necessary. (This might require remote Xdebug if you're working with PHP, but no matter what you're using on your server, most web application tools offer some form of interactive debugging.)

**Network Troubleshooting**

If none of this works, it's possible that the gateway simply can't reach the host and port you're running this on, or that you have some other kind of network connectivity issue. I would run `tcpdump` on your Ubuntu box to capture the network traffic. If you can recreate this on a quiet (network) system, that will be to your advantage. Still, it's TLS (https), so don't expect to see much other than that the connection opens and packets are arriving. If you find that you need to see inside the TLS traffic in order to troubleshoot, you might consider using `mitmproxy` to do so.

Comment: Inspecing the request seems the logical place to start but I seem to be having trouble with that. I adding the `log_format` config to the `location` block on the `server` but I get an error `"log_format" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo.com`. So I moved to the `http` on the default nginx config in the hope that I'd capture post requests to ALL URLs but I'm not getting any data logged at all - from any form posts.

Comment: I haven't tried this with a virtual host / server block. Have you tried moving the `log_format` directive somewhere else, for example before the server block? And then leave the `access_log` directive inside the `server`'s `location` block...